# Incorrect file encoding to parse

Tags: java

I have a problem parsing the file. The input file is EE windows 1250 encoded. When trying to parse it gets an error

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: MalformedInputException reading next record: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
        at org.apache.commons.csv.CSVParser$CSVRecordIterator.getNextRecord(CSVParser.java:145)
        at org.apache.commons.csv.CSVParser$CSVRecordIterator.hasNext(CSVParser.java:155)
        at com.test.converter.CsvConverter.processInputCSV(CsvConverter.java:148)
        at com.test.converter.CsvConverter.main(CsvConverter.java:249)
    Caused by: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1
        at java.base/java.nio.charset.CoderResult.throwException(CoderResult.java:274)
    Caused by: java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length =
```

My method

```
public List<CSVRecord> collectAllEntries(Path path) throws IOException {
        List<CSVRecord> store = new ArrayList<>();
        try (
                Reader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(path);
                CSVParser csvParser = new CSVParser(reader, CSVFormat.EXCEL)
        ) {
            for (CSVRecord csvRecord : csvParser) {
                store.add(csvRecord);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
        return store;
    }
```

How I can fix this problem ?

Comment: According to the stack trace you posted, the exception is being thrown in method `processInputCSV` of class `com.test.converter.CsvConverter`. Pardon me, but I couldn't find that code in your question.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is you are trying to read a `windows-1250` encoded file using `UTF-8`. The `Files.newBufferedReader(path)` defaults to `UTF-8`.

When you read the file, pass the encoding scheme (`windows-1250` in this case) that the file was encoded to instruct the buffered reader to use it as below;

```
Files.newBufferedReader(path, Charset.forName("windows-1250"));
```

This is a good start on encoding - https://www.baeldung.com/java-char-encoding

Answer (score 0):

You have a BufferedReader using the default encoding, which is probably UTF-8.

You have a file that you have said is encoded as code page 1250.

That is the reason. Your BufferedReader needs to be told to expect that encoding it will be given.

Use the two-argument form of newBufferedReader, the one with a character-set as the second arg. I'm not sure what the right value for CP 1250 is, but that should be easy to find out.

Comment: _which is probably UTF-8_ - this statement is incorrect. It is __definitely__ UTF-8; unlike most of the core library API, all methods in Files that implicitly convert bytes to chars or vice versa and which do not include an explicit charset encoding as parameter use UTF-8 and not 'platform default encoding'.

Comment: thanks for the detail, though of course it doesn't detract from the main point of "you need to ask for what you expect".